# Why does this integer return 0 although it's not 0?

Tags: java, swing, variables, integer

I'm creating a software that's supposed to execute a console command. The command varies on your configuration you set up in the actual application.

The problem is, one of the commands (4 in total) needs to catch an integer in order to work for the configuration.

The integer is set by a dropdown list via this code:

```
private String[] osList = {"Choose OS", "Windows 7 Pro", "Windows 7 Home Basic", "Windows 7 Home Premium", "Windows 7 Ultimate"};
private JComboBox osDropDown = new JComboBox(osList);
public int osIndex;

osDropDown.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    Object item = e.getItem();

                    if(item.equals(osList[1])) {
                        osIndex = 3;
                    } else if(item.equals(osList[2])) {
                        osIndex = 1;
                    } else if(item.equals(osList[3])) {
                        osIndex = 2;
                    } else if(item.equals(osList[4])) {
                        osIndex = 4;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

As you can see, the variable osIndex is supposed to be set to 3 for example if you chose "Windows 7 pro".
This is the command that's executed:

```
"dism /mount-wim /wimfile:install.wim /index:" + formPanel.osIndex + " /mountdir:mount"
```

But for some weird reason, it returns 0 on osIndex no matter which item in the list I choose.. And I have no idea why?

If I use this code, it outputs the correct value of osIndex when I choose that on the list. But when I try to run the command after choosing, it still returns 0.

```
if(item.equals(osList[1])) {
    osIndex = 3;
    System.out.println(osList[1] + " [" + osIndex + "]");
} else if(item.equals(osList[2])) {
    osIndex = 1;
    System.out.println(osList[2] + " [" + osIndex + "]");
} else if(item.equals(osList[3])) {
    osIndex = 2;
    System.out.println(osList[3] + " [" + osIndex + "]");
} else if(item.equals(osList[4])) {
    osIndex = 4;
    System.out.println(osList[4] + " [" + osIndex + "]");
}
```

EDIT: It seems that the command in the array is set and not changed once I change the item in the list. I need to, somehow, make it so when I change the list item; that's the point where the command in the array is assigned to the variable. Any good ideas on how to do this?

EDIT 2: Solved it by doing this; once I click the "Go" button, it sets the commands text in the array to:

```
cmdExec.cmd[3] = "dism /mount-wim /wimfile:install.wim /index:" + formPanel.getOsIndex() + " /mountdir:mount";
```

There's no way that this is the best solution, but it was pretty much the only one I could currently figure out. If there's anyone with any better idea, please let me know!

Comment: Perhaps `e.getItem()` is not equal to any of the Strings you compare it to.

Comment: Because none of the if statements were entered...

Comment: Because the default value of a field is `0`, and your listener is probably never executed or never reaches `osIndex = 3`.

Comment: Where is the code generating the command? In particular: Is it perhaps being run **before** the event occurs? You'd need to run it *within* the listener, not outside it.

Comment: @Eran check my edit on the post, that should mean that `e.getItem()` works fine, right?

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple instances of the class that contains the `osIndex` member. You might be setting it to 3 in one instance and seeing it still having a 0 value in another instance.

Comment: I just realized that I'm quite stupid. @T.J.Crowder was right I think, it seems logical. Since the command is set to the integer once it starts. I should make it so the command inputs the integer once I click on a button or something AFTER choosing the item in the list.

It has something to do with the command getting the variable before it's set by the list. Not sure how to fix this in a smart way though..

Comment: Without a runnable example, anything we suggest is just guess work

Comment: What's the difference between `formPanel.osIndex` and `formPanel.getOsIndex()`?

Comment: @cricket_007 there's no difference, I was just playing around a bit, checking if it was smarter to get the value via a method or just straight from the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is "returned". The default value simply isn't re-assigned.

Real test - Use a debugger and set some breakpoints. System.out is a flaky way to test something

But since your strings are printing fine, it seems you are needing to create a new command string each time you update that osIndex variable

Comment: Based on the OPs edit, the if statements (and the comparisons) work correctly.

Comment: It's not clear where that code is called from, though

Comment: @Eran I updated the original post with what the issue actually is. So now I know the issue (atleast some sort of progress) but not sure how to update it

Comment: Just because ItemEvent#getItem returns a Object, the (in this case) is still a String, so item.equals is still going to be calling String.equals, it's how polymorphism works